# How to display image to right of radio button and check box

Tags: android

I am working on talking multiple choice test.

I have some images as answers that are single choice and multiple choice.

```
<radio button or checkbox here>  <image here>
```

I need to add the imgages to right of radiobuttons or checkboxes `programatically` from drawable folder

How to acheive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your xml file..

```
<RadioButton
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
```

EDIT

Sorry..

May be you are looking for this..

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        rb.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, d, null);
```

Comment: will it apply for check box also?